# How to dynamically add Entity in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, data-persistence

I'm a java developer. I'm using [spring 4.0.1](https://spring.io) and [hibernate 4.2.21](http://hibernate.org). I have a class as follow:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(...)
public abstract class Feature{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   protected Long id;

   ...

}
```

Now I have some many class as follow:

**Label.java class:**

```
@Entity
public class Label extends Feature{
   protected String str;

   ...
}
```

**Point.java class:**

```
@Entity
public class Point extends Feature{
   protected Integer intg;

   ...
}
```

I have more than 20 Entity class that extends from `Feature` class. Is there any way to add dynamically this classes(such as `Label` and `Point`) to the project without writing hard code?

**update**:

For example, Hibernate get data from a database and then according this data, create models.

1. Is it possible?
2. How do I do?

Comment: Try to describe your problem in a better way? If I understood what are you saying, you can to generate all entities automatically using jpa tools in your ide

Comment: What do you mean by `There is a way to add dynamically this classes(such as Label and Point) to the project without writing hard code?`

I think by now you should be familiar on how to ask question!

Comment: I have more than 20 Entity that extends form `Feature`. I want to when the project deployed, it generate all these classes automatically.

Comment: Concerning your update: Please have a look at my answer :-) There is a tool for creating entities from database structure

Comment: @mortezamalvandi : Did you try as I have mentioned in my answer? What is the result?

Comment: yeah of course. thanks for your answer. But I don't want what you said. I want thing that Admin system can Add Entity NOT developer with Eclipse.

Comment: @mortezamalvandi Ok. Glad you've resolved the issue.

Comment: You may also refer to this question and answers where they are trying to do something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371536/hibernate-create-entitywith-annotations-in-runtime

Answer (score 6):

I think its not a good database design that needs to be changed dynamically. It sounds verbose and not consistent. Observe your domain again and try to design a proper entity relationships that wouldnt be changed over run time.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to collect the needed data to build the model and generate a hibernate `hbm.xml` file for each entity (is xml format and easy to generate with java after reading the data needed as you describe in your update)

After that, you can create programmatically a hibernate configuration object following this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

I Think with that approach you can achieve what you want if I understand well your question.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to generate your entity class at runtime instead of that you have to write your java file and compile it and so on.
If this is your requirement you can use a byte code generator like **javassist** to generate and annotate your class file at runtime. Then you can persist it to your table using JPA, Hibernate and any other ORM framework.

Comment: Hi, is your project finished?

Comment: Did you finish your generator? Is it working as expected?

Comment: Authority declares opposite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330810/jpa-hibernate-dynamic-entity-mapping-persistence-at-runtime/47331023

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you need to develop a tool, collects table names that have one-to-one relationship with `Feature` table.

My suggestion is like that (tested with Oracle):

1) From your DB, get tables metadata who is referancing your Feature table.
Below will print your Label, Point, etc tables who has foreign key relation to your table.
If you want to only generate a subset (irrelevant tables might has this relationship too) may be you put a **common** foreign key column name and filter out non-related tables with a help of such marking.

```
Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();

ResultSet exportedKeys = metaData.getExportedKeys(connection.getCatalog(), "<your_schema_name>", "FEATURE");
while (exportedKeys.next()){
    String fkTableName = exportedKeys.getString("FKTABLE_NAME");
    String fkColumnName = exportedKeys.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");  
    System.out.println("[fkTableName:" + fkTableName + "], [fkColumnName" + fkColumnName + "]");
}
exportedKeys.close();
```

2) For the tables you collected above, for each table of our concern, get table metadata for the types and columns.

```
ResultSet columns = metaData.getColumns(connection.getCatalog(), "<your_schema_name>", "<your_table_name>", null);
while (columns.next()){
    String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    String typeName = columns.getString("TYPE_NAME");
    System.out.println("[columnName:" + columnName + "], [typeName" + typeName + "]");
}
columns.close();
```

3) According to result from 2 generate your Java classes. With fields, getter setters, annotations etc. Then copy them into your source directory. You know the rest :) 
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is a good idea but at 3rd step generating java classes is not enough for persisting objects at runtime. You need to compile generated source files inorder to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Hibernate Reverse Engineering to generate Entity for all the database tables. Please refer [this](http://omtlab.com/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-eclipse-tutorial/) Link. That will explained step by step process to generate entity from database using hibernate reverse engineering.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not repeat yourself.**

If you really need those classes use an IDE (like eclipse) to generate the classes. Or use generics and inheritance to create only one class that is capable of storing Strings as well as Integers.

But if you do not actually *need* classes, generate SQL (not JPQL nor HQL) and to store the data in `java.util.Map` and similar data structures.

Classes are good for:

- type safety
- combining logic (methods) with data (fields)
- describing relationships

In your case you might only need:

- store structured data at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with eclipse, but the classes had to be modified more or less to preserve the inheritance hierarchy.

- Righ click on the project name and select **Properties**
- Use project facets if project facets not enabled

[image]

- Click the **JPA** if it's not selected, then click **OK** to close the project properties window.
- After enabling JPA in project properties, now right click you eclipse project name again, you should see a new context menu item **JPA tools** appears. Choose **Generate Entities from tables**

[image]

Select a database connection to let Eclipse get the tables  used to generated 
class from.

Here is [how to setup db in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html)

- It's better to create the entities in a dummy project using the above method and copy the Entity classes to the real project.
- Eclipse's Class refactoring may be used to preserve the inheritance hierarchy that you want.

Hope this helps.